# Set serializer geo_field as PointField from another model - Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, gis, geojson, geodjango

I have two models and need to serialize `Article` as Geojson by setting the `geo_field` attribute as `point` from the `Location` model. After following the solution given [here](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/issues/49#issuecomment-99209361) I get the error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `point` on serializer `ArticleSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Article` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'point'.
```

Here are my models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Article(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def point(self):
    return self.locations.point
```

And my serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
point = GeometryField()

class Meta:
    model = Article
    geo_field = "point"
    id_field = False
    fields = ('pub_date', 'point',)
```

Any help appreciated. I've been trying to find a solution to this for ages with little success!

UPDATE!

Ok, getting somewhere with this. I created a `LocationSerializer` and reference this in `ArticleSerializer`. These now look something like this:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        geo_field = "point"
        id_field = False
        fields = ('point',)

class ArticleSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True)       
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        geo_field = "locations"
        id_field = False
        fields = ('pub_date', 'locations',)
```

The output is closer to what I want...but still a bit obscure in construct:

```
{  
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[  
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "geometry":[  
                {  
                    "point":{  
                        "type":"Point",
                        "coordinates":[  
                            -2.200337956118645,
                            53.48316423741371
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "point":{  
                        "type":"Point",
                        "coordinates":[  
                            0.041198730463564,
                            51.51002453017606
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties":{  
                "pub_date":"2015-04-06T20:38:59Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE!

The format I require is:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "time": "2013-01-22 08:42:26+01"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    7.582512743,
                    51.933292258,
                    1
                ]
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `point` property on the `Article` model is referring to `self.locations` which is a `ManyToManyField`. You are calling `self.locations.point` as though `self.locations` is a `ForeignKey` which is why you are getting your error.

> 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'point'.

Means that `self.locations` is returning a `ManyRelatedManager`, which makes sense for a `ManyToManyField`. Since you are only expecting a single object, that means you need to make one of two changes

1. You really were looking to have `locations` be a `ForeignKey`, which would mean your `point` property is correct.
2. You are actually expecting multiple locations for an `Article`, and your `point` property should actually be returning a list of points.

   ```
   return [location.point for location in self.locations]
   ```

If you are actually looking for multiple locations, you are also going to want to set `many=True` on your `GeometryField` on your serializer.

Comment: Yeah I am expecting either one or more `locations` for each `Article`. I've tried making the changes but `GeometryField` doesn't like to be set to `many`, I am getting the error: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'`. Without setting this I get the error: `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm a bit closer. I added `.all()` to the `self.locations` and am now getting `Improper geometry input type: <type 'list'>` error. Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like the `GeometryField` is only designed to work with a single point, you might have some luck wrapping it in a `ListField`.

Comment: Updated my question above. Don't know if this spurs any thoughts?

Comment: @sammy88888888 Is the output what you are expecting or are you looking for something different?

Comment: I'm looking for something different, I've udated above to show the required format. The idea is to serialize as geojson and pass to [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution seems to be...don't do it the way I was attempting. I've got round the bulk of the problem by using vectorformats.DjangoWStyle (just search google) to deal with searializing geojson from two models. Also, attempting a reverse relationship to achives this will lead to a world of misery. Instead I added the `ManyToManyField` on `Location` model, referencing the `Article` model.