# Error when serializing foreign key object with django-rest-framework-gis to geojson

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, geojson, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

I am trying to serialize into geojson a model with a foreign key that has a geometry field. I am using the django-rest-framework-gis. I am using django 2.2

I'm stuck on this and none of the other related answers on Stack Overflow work for me. e.g. I have tried versions of this:

- [How can I flatten a foreignkey object with django-rest-framework-(gis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857249/how-can-i-flatten-a-foreignkey-object-with-django-rest-framework-gis)
- [Set serializer geo_field as PointField from another model - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062905/set-serializer-geo-field-as-pointfield-from-another-model-django)

The problem is I get this error:
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'statements.models.Response'>`

**Models:**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Hexgrid_10km2(models.Model):
    lng = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    polygon = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
    centroid = models.PointField(default=Point(0,0), srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'lng: { self.lng } lat: {self.lat }'


class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    statement = models.ForeignKey(Statement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hexgrid_10km2 = models.ForeignKey(Hexgrid_10km2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
        def polygon(self):
            return self.hexgrid_10km2.polygon
```

**Views**

```
class ResponseHeatmapAPIView(APIView): #ReadOnly

    def get(self, request, pk):
        final = Response.objects.all()
        serializer = ResponseHeatmapSerializer(final, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializers**

```
class ResponseHeatmapSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    """ A class to serialize hex polygons as GeoJSON compatible data """

    hexgrid_10km2 = GeometrySerializerMethodField()

    def get_hexgrid_10km2(self, obj):
        return obj.hexgrid_10km2.polygon

    class Meta:
        model = Response
        geo_field = 'hexgrid_10km2'
        id_field = False
        fields = ('id',)
```

**Traceback**

```
OrderedDict([('type', 'FeatureCollection'), ('features', [OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('type', 'Feature'), ('geometry', GeoJsonDict([('type', 'MultiPolygon'), ('coordinates', [[[[0.52353663711945, 50.8631481850499], [0.538799411254891, 50.86870974483], [0.554062185390241, 50.8631481850499], [0.554062185390241, 50.852023074998], [0.548895002474644, 50.85013962], [0.540831980000019, 50.85013962], [0.53199000192362, 50.8489417564374], [0.52353663711945, 50.852023074998], [0.52353663711945, 50.8631481850499]]]])])), ('properties', OrderedDict([('response_date', '2020-04-15T21:04:04.599597Z'), ('agree', 1), ('hasLocation', False), ('location', GeoJsonDict([('type', 'Point'), ('coordinates', [0.550660257722784, 50.851541821108924])])), ('latitude', 50.851541821108924), ('longitude', 0.5506602577227836), ('locationAccuracy', 0.0), ('user', 1), ('statement', 1)]))])])])
Internal Server Error: /statements/api/heatmap/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 507, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Documents\django\karate-project-2.2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 419, in finalize_response
    assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'statements.models.Response'>`
[15/Apr/2020 21:55:04] "GET /statements/api/heatmap/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 89414
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializer is waiting for data from you. I got the same error when I tried your view with a simple modeling. I think there is something wrong with the definition. can you try the presentation:

```
def get(self, request):
    final = Response.objects.all()
    serializer = ResponseHeatmapSerializer(data=final, many=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**EDITED:**

Please excuse me because of my sleeplessness.

The ***BIG*** problem here is the name of the table: ***Response***. You have to change the name; somehow it conflicts with the 'Response' that the RestAPI uses.

- Change Response(model.Model)'s name to different name.
- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate

and the view is ready to run (I changed the model name to **'Strawberry'**:

```
class ResponseHeatmapList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        final = Strawberry.objects.all()
        serializer = ResponseHeatmapSerializer(final, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class ResponseHeatmapDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Strawberry.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Strawberry.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        final = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ResponseHeatmapSerializer(final)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thankyou, Metehan. I didn't get an error, but the API browser showed this:                              'HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"."
    ]
}'

Comment: I'm so sorry, I guess my sleeplessness struck me tonight. I read the problem completely wrong. I will make the necessary correction and edit. Now I'm testing, if I can't find the solution, I will delete the comment.

Comment: That worked. It was the naming issue as you said. Many thanks, Metehan!!!